# modificar um input e fazer o update

Tags: php, ajax

**php**

alguém poderia me dar dicas de implementar uma parte?
eu mandei imprimir um input do tipo text dentro do loop do while: `"<td><input type='text' value='".$valor['url_video']."'  style='width: 400px;' id='url-video'></td>".` , dentro desse input é printado o valor `url_video`, ao clicar no btn de update, eu mando ele atualizar o campo de input selecionado `var string = $('#url-video').val();` o problema é que ele só atualiza a primeira coluna `url_video`, está dando problema nos demais (é feito apenas uma copia dessa primeira pros demais campos).  acho que o problema está quando seto o meu input como `id='url-video'`, não é? vocês podem me dar dicas?

```
    echo "<table class='table'>".
        "<thead>".
             "<tr>".
                "<td>ID</td>".
                "<td>url_video</td>".
             "</tr>".
        "</thead><tbody>";
while($valor = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    echo "<tr>".
            "<td>".$valor['ID']."</td>".
            "<td><input type='text' value='".$valor['url_video']."'  style='width: 400px;' id='url-video'></td>".
            "<td><input type='button' value='Update' class='btn-update' data-id='".$valor['ID']."' >"."</td>".
         "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

**ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btn-update').click(function(){
        var id = $('.btn-update').data('id');
        var string = $('#url_video').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "tabelaUpdate.php",
            data: { 'idDeUpdate' : id,
                    'url_video' : string
                  },
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                //alert("ok"+response);
                $('#result').html(response); //serve para ver a array foi inserida mesmo
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar `id` dessa forma dentro de um loop é inviável. IDs são ÚNICOS, se tiver dois iguais na mesma página o JS dá pala.

Solução (Adicionei a ID do Vídeo na ID do Input):

```
while($valor = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    echo "<tr>".
            "<td>".$valor['ID']."</td>".
            "<td><input type='text' value='".$valor['url_video']."'  style='width: 400px;' id='url-video-".$valor['ID']."'></td>".
            "<td><input type='button' value='Update' class='btn-update' data-id='".$valor['ID']."' >"."</td>".
         "</tr>";
}
```

E o JS recupera o campo certo, usando a ID do botão:

```
$('.btn-update').click(function(){
    var id = $('.btn-update').data('id');
    var string = $('#url_video-'+id).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "tabelaUpdate.php",
        data: { 'idDeUpdate' : id,
                'url_video' : string
              },
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            //alert("ok"+response);
            $('#result').html(response); //serve para ver a array foi inserida mesmo
        }
    })
});
```